# Why does $\epsilon_0=1$ in CGS units?

Tags: units, si-units, unit-conversion, metrology

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre%E2%80%93gram%E2%80%93second_system_of_units#Various_extensions_of_the_CGS_system_to_electromagnetism) gives a table of certain constants in different systems of units. I noticed that in Gaussian and electrostatic CGS the value of $\epsilon_0$ equals the dimensionless $1$.

I wondered whether anyone could provide justification for this? I was under the impression that $\epsilon_0$ is not even necessary in these units since it's essentially just a dimensional conversion factor in the SI, however I suppose it would still be possible to convert it into CGS units. How is this done?

Comment: Generally speaking, CGS was constructed that way.

Comment: Actually to convert from mks to cgs you set $\epsilon_0=1/4\pi$.

Comment: @my2cts I don't think that is correct, it is not as simple as that. The dimensions of charge are different in the two systems of units. $\epsilon_0$ is set to 1, as is stated in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: I agree with @my2cts. I have no idea how Wikipedia can compare Coulomb’s Law in SI units, $F=q_1q_2/4\pi\epsilon_0r^2$, with Coulomb’s Law in Gaussian units, $F=q_1q_2/r_2$, and conclude that in Gaussian units $\epsilon_0$ is $1$ in any sense. To me this is patently incorrect.

Comment: @G.Smith My point was that you can't just write $\frac{q_1 q_2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2} = \frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}$ and deduce that $\epsilon_0 = \frac{1}{4\pi}$ in Gaussian units, it is not that straightforward. The *dimensions* of the quantity of charge itself is different in the two systems of units, i.e. in CGS it is defined entirely from mechanical units.

Comment: So there is no contradiction in setting $\epsilon_0 = 1$ in CGS units since neither it nor $4\pi$ feature in the definition of Coulomb's Law. In fact for clarity we should probably distinguish the charge with different dimensions as $F = \frac{q_1 q_2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2} = \frac{\tilde{q_1} \tilde{q_2}}{r^2}$. This is now a correct relation, and we can say $q = \sqrt{4\pi \epsilon_0} \tilde{q}$ with the $\sqrt{4\pi \epsilon_0}$ as a dimensional conversion factor. It then doesn't too much matter what we set $\epsilon_0$ to in CGS units. So 1 is just as valid a choice.

Comment: Of course *to convert* a formula from SI to Gaussian we can simply replace $\epsilon_0$ in the SI formula with $\frac{1}{4\pi}$. However this by no means implies that those two things are equal, for reasons stated above! Jackson seems to agree with Wikipedia, as can be seen here (and also in the last paragraph of Dale's answer): https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/501191/confusion-on-the-cgs-heavside-lorentz-and-si-system?rq=1

Comment: I am well aware that charge has different dimensions in the two systems. I find Jackson’s table as baffling as Wikipedia’s. I used to teach electromagnetism from Jackson but that was when his book used Gaussian units. From my point of view, there is no $\epsilon_0$ in Gaussian EM and it has no “value” in Gaussian units. To *convert* equations from SI to Gaussian one replaces $1/4\pi\epsilon_0$ with $1$.

Comment: @G.Smith Thanks for your comment, that makes things very clear to me! I completely agree, the reason I became confused in the first place was that I wasn't sure *why* there would even be an $\epsilon_0$ in the first place in Gaussian units! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the best way to see this is to consider Coulomb's Law that gives the force F (in Newtons) between two charges $Q_1, Q_2$ (in Coulomb) separated by a distance $R$ (in m): $$F = \frac{Q_1 Q_2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 R^2}.$$
In cgs units the force is measured in dyne, $1 N = 10^5 dyne$, the unit of length is measured in cm, $1 m = 100 cm$. So if you measure force, f, in dyne and separation, r, in cm then
$$10^{-5} f = \frac{Q_1 Q_2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 (10^{-2} r)^2}.$$
You can now define a charge $q$ by $q = Q/\sqrt{10^{
+5} \times 4 \pi \epsilon_0 \times 10^{-4}}$ then Coulombs Law becomes $$f = \frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}.$$ It follows that the relationship between charge in SI units and cgs units is $$q (Fr) \equiv 2997919999.934 \,\,\, Q (C)$$

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The one thing I would comment is that $q \neq 2997919999.934Q$ since $q$ and $Q$ have different dimensions in the two systems of units; this is the reason why the physical law looks different in both systems of units (which is generally unusual, but a thing in electromagnetism!). It is better to state $q \leftrightarrow 2997919999.934Q$.

Comment: @JamesWirth Well, yes I agree with you it is a conversion factor, I have changed $q = ....$ to $q \equiv ...$

Comment: Why is your constant so different from the speed of light $c=299\,792\,458\,\mathrm{m/s}$?

Comment: @Ruslan The constant relating charge measured in $Fr$ to charge measured in $C$ doesn't have units of $m/s$. That the value has the same numbers as the the speed of light is because $\mu_0 \approx 4 \pi \times 10^{-7} H m^{-1}$ (at one time $\mu_0$ was defined as exactly $4 \pi \times 10^{-7} H m^{-1}$ but this changed in CODATA 2018), so that $4 \pi \epsilon_0$ is conveniently related to the (SI) value of $c$.

Comment: @Ruslan in fact the definition of $\mu_0$ was changed in 2019, so that every book on electromagnetism where you see the statement $\mu_0 = 4 \pi \times 10^{-7} H m^{-1}$ are now technically incorrect.

Comment: @jim The BIPM is the authority which manage the (Revised) International System of Units, but it has no competence at all on the Gaussian system(s) of units, largely used in theoretical physics.
As has already been noted, in the Gaussian system the constants $\epsilon_o$ and $\mu_o$ simply don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The value of $\epsilon_o$ alone is meaningless,
but the question becomes meaningful if examined in a wider perspective.

For historical reasons electromagnetism was developed following
various formal schemes (characterized by different definitions of some quantities).
Consequently many mathematical formulae, dimensions of quantities and
systems of units don't match.
This may be a bit annoying when looking at different textbooks
and when we need to compare units with not equivalent dimensions.

This well known formal problem can be solved by building an "ancestor" system
having three arbitrary constants, as shown by Wikipedia and Jackson.
Each formal scheme is uniquely determined by a suitable set of constants,
that enable us to write all electromagnetic relations
in every form, as well as to find all dimensional relationships (allowing
an automatic conversion of units belonging to totally different systems).

A good choise of the parameters is tabulated below.\
Here the three constants $k_o,\epsilon_o,\mu_o $ are indipendent,
instead  $\chi = c\sqrt{(\epsilon_o \mu_o)}$ and $\xi = \frac{1}{(\epsilon_o k_o)} $
are two useful dependent parameters.

\begin{array}{|l||c|c|c||c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Formal system}  \rule{0pt}{14pt} \rule[-8pt]{0pt}{12pt}  
& \quad k_o\quad & \quad k_o\epsilon_o \quad & \quad \epsilon_o\mu_o \quad & \ \chi \ &  \xi  \\
\hline
\text{BIPM - SI}  \rule{0pt}{18pt}  & k_o & \frac{1}{4\pi} & \frac{1}{c^2}   & 1 & 4\pi \\
\text{ES abs}   \rule{0pt}{14pt}  & 1   & 1   & \frac{1}{c^2} &   1 & 1 \\
\text{EM abs}   \rule{0pt}{14pt}  & c^2 & 1 & \frac{1}{c^2} &  1 & 1 \\
\text{Gauss}         \rule{0pt}{14pt}  & 1   & 1 & 1 &  c & 1 \\
\text{Heaviside}     \rule{0pt}{14pt}
             \rule[-10pt]{0pt}{10pt}   & \frac{1}{4\pi} & \frac{1}{4\pi} & 1   & c & 4\pi \\
\hline
\end{array}

So e.g. Maxwell's equations can be written in a general form,
which easily includes all schemes as special cases.

\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
& \nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{D}   = \frac{4\pi}{\xi} \rho  
 && \boldsymbol{D}     = \epsilon_o\boldsymbol{E} + \frac{4\pi}{\xi}\boldsymbol{P} \\
& \nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{B}   = 0 \\
& \nabla\times\boldsymbol{E}  = -\frac{1}{\chi}\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{B}}{\partial t} \\
& \nabla\times\boldsymbol{H}  = \frac{4\pi}{\xi\chi}\boldsymbol{J} + 
\frac{1}{\chi}\,\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{D}}{\partial t} \qquad 
 && \boldsymbol{H} = \frac{\boldsymbol{B}}{\mu_o} - \frac{4\pi}{\xi}\boldsymbol{M}  \\
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}